# How to populate a group update sql into single update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I would like to turn a group query into multiple single queries. I can write this manually, but what if there is over 600 rows I need to work on?

```
"Update TABLE SET VAL = 'BB' where VAL = 'AV'"
```

This will update the TABLE with id = 1, id = 2,... up to id = 300.
Instead of a group update, I want an easy way to convert it into multiple single updates.
To

```
Update TABLE SET VAL = 'BB' where ID = 1;
Update TABLE SET VAL = 'BB' where ID = 2;
......
Update TABLE SET VAL = 'BB' where ID = 300;
```

Is there anyway to expand a group into singular query? I'm using Oracle SQL

Comment: XX is some digits.

Comment: I want to convert into multiple single update queries instead of a group update query

Comment: Please explain a little more.

Comment: `select 'update <T> set val = ''BB'' where ID = ' || cast(ID as varchar(3)) || ';' from <T>;`

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . That's interesting. Your comment suggests or inspires to use dynamic SQL to generate and execute each separate UPDATE statement in a loop? I am not familiar with Oracle, but perhaps this is possible using PL/SQL?

Comment: You can generate the SQL string easily. I don't know how OP intends to use it though..

Comment: @shawnt00 I tried your query and it is pretty close. The where ID = ' || cast(ID as varchar(3)) || ';' doesn't show the ID I want. I want all the id with the condition VAL = 'AV'.

Comment: So change it to VAL. Maybe throw in `select distinct` to avoid duplicates on a non PK column. (If there's a connection between VAL and ID then you'll need to explain.)

Comment: @shawnt00 u solved my question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition is same in all three query single query will do your job. You just forgot to include table name (yourtable).

```
Update TABLE yourtable SET VAL = 'BB' where ID = XX;
```

If you are trying to update `yourtable` with VAL 'BB' for multiple IDs then you can use IN:

```
Update TABLE yourtable SET VAL = 'BB' where ID in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: Not the answer im looking for. I want multiple query, with each query 1 row update. And what if there are 600 ID? I need an easy way to convert